# magento 1.9 pagination doesn't want to limit the category products

Tags: magento, categories

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Category Product Gird suppose to show 24 products, but instead of it loads the entire catalog, and pages doesn't work...

It should be 190 pages with 24 products on each, but instead is ONE PAGE with all products:

[image]

First we thought the reason is in Layered Navigation, but we tried to turn it off. Still the same issue.

Could someone suggest what might cause the problem?
Where should I look for the answer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please disable flat tables if used and  reindex all the indexes and clear the cache.

If above solution doesn't work then pagination need to be checked also check in the log files ,There might be some clue